# reportng report overwrites previous one if run multiple test suites

Tags: webdriver, reportng

for example, if I run the testng.xml and it contains multiple test suites

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Master Suite">
    <suite-files>
        <suite-file path="test_1.xml"></suite-file>
        <suite-file path="test_2.xml"></suite-file>
    </suite-files>
</suite>
```

after, I checked reportng report, it did not display both test suites report but only the last one. How to avoid overwriting previous test report?

please help

Answer (score 0):

dont add listeners in suite files add those in ur testng.xml

this will solve ur issue.

Comment: do you mean remove the listener from suite tag?

Comment: <suite name="xxx" parallel="none">
 <listeners>
  <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter"/>
  <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter"/>
 </listeners>

Comment: Dont put listeners in test_1.xml and test_2.xml only put in testng.xml